# pytesseract.image_to_string(im) not able to access the input file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to read text from an image using pytesseract. Using the following two commands. Image.open does return the image properly, but the next command fails with windows error of file not found.

First of all I don't understand, why it is trying to read the image from the disk, as it is already read by previous statement and image im is already in the memory.
Then I have included the directory where pytesseract.exe is, in the path of environment variables, as suggested by some one. Still the same issue persists.

I am using anaconda distribution of python 3.5 on windows 10. Running the code from Jupyter Notebook, not python command line.

Installed pytesseract using pip, and corresponding import statement in jupyter notebook get executed without any error.

appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

```
im = Image.open('test_image1.png')  
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```

> FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 im = Image.open('test_image1.png')
>   ----> 2 text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\keras35\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py
>   in image_to_string(image, lang, config, nice, boxes, output_type)
>       191         return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice, True)
>       192 
>   --> 193     return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice)
>       194 
>       195
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\keras35\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py
>   in run_and_get_output(image, extension, lang, config, nice,
>   return_bytes)
>       138         }
>       139 
>   --> 140         run_tesseract(**kwargs)
>       141         filename = kwargs['output_filename_base'] + os.extsep + extension
>       142         with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\keras35\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py
>   in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension,
>   lang, config, nice)
>       109         command.append(extension)
>       110 
>   --> 111     proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>       112     status_code, error_string = proc.wait(), proc.stderr.read()
>       113     proc.stderr.close()
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\keras35\lib\subprocess.py in **init**(self, args,
>   bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds,
>   shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags,
>   restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds)
>       674                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
>       675                                 errread, errwrite,
>   --> 676                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
>       677         except:
>       678             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\keras35\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self,
>   args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env,
>   startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread,
>   c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals,
>   unused_start_new_session)
>       955                                          env,
>       956                                          cwd,
>   --> 957                                          startupinfo)
>       958             finally:
>       959                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I am having same issue.

Comment: Mine is resolved. I tried several ways. First did you restart your computer after downloading the package? I tested my package on windows power shell and then tried in python. i got some other errors with path and unicode. i solved by using Path package and encoding. let me know, how is it going on your end.

Comment: yes. Issue was not with input file, but it was not finding some tesseract modules. I had to set up right path in environment variable, then it worked fine.